# Bitmap not load properly in Linear Layout

Tags: android

I am trying to create an application in which I need to add freehand cropping feature. I used https://github.com/TomiGie/Android-FreeHandCropView this project to integrate it into my project.

Problem is when I am trying to add an image which is captured from the camera seems very big in the view and I can't able to crop the complete image.
Here is the code which I tried.

This is the CropView which has the cropping code.

```
package com.idoideas.stickermaker.WhatsAppBasedCode;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.DashPathEffect;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CropView extends View implements View.OnTouchListener {
private Paint paint;
private List<Point> points;

boolean flgPathDraw = true;

Point mfirstpoint = null;
boolean bfirstpoint;

Point mlastpoint = null;

Bitmap bitmap;

Context mContext;


public CropView(Context c, Bitmap bitmap) {
    super(c);

    mContext = c;
    this.bitmap = bitmap;

    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

    paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[]{10, 20}, 0));
    paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);

    this.setOnTouchListener(this);
    points = new ArrayList<>();

    bfirstpoint = false;
}

public CropView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    mContext = context;
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

    paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);

    points = new ArrayList<>();
    bfirstpoint = false;

    this.setOnTouchListener(this);
}

public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        /*Rect dest = new Rect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

 paint.setFilterBitmap(true); canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, null, dest, paint);*/
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);

    Path path = new Path();
    boolean first = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i += 2) {
        Point point = points.get(i);
        if (first) {
            first = false;
            path.moveTo(point.x, point.y);
        } else if (i < points.size() - 1) {
            Point next = points.get(i + 1);
            path.quadTo(point.x, point.y, next.x, next.y);
        } else {
            mlastpoint = points.get(i);
            path.lineTo(point.x, point.y);
        }
    }
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
}

public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    // if(event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    // return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    Point point = new Point();
    point.x = (int) event.getX();
    point.y = (int) event.getY();

    if (flgPathDraw) {

        if (bfirstpoint) {

            if (comparepoint(mfirstpoint, point)) {
                // points.add(point);
                points.add(mfirstpoint);
                flgPathDraw = false;
                showcropdialog();
            } else {
                points.add(point);
            }
        } else {
            points.add(point);
        }

        if (!(bfirstpoint)) {

            mfirstpoint = point;
            bfirstpoint = true;
        }
    }

    invalidate();
    Log.e("Hi  ==>", "Size: " + point.x + " " + point.y);

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        Log.d("Action up*****~~>>>>", "called");
        mlastpoint = point;
        if (flgPathDraw) {
            if (points.size() > 12) {
                if (!comparepoint(mfirstpoint, mlastpoint)) {
                    flgPathDraw = false;
                    points.add(mfirstpoint);
                    showcropdialog();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}

private boolean comparepoint(Point first, Point current) {
    int left_range_x = current.x - 3;
    int left_range_y = current.y - 3;

    int right_range_x = current.x + 3;
    int right_range_y = current.y + 3;

    if ((left_range_x < first.x && first.x < right_range_x)
            && (left_range_y < first.y && first.y < right_range_y)) {
        return points.size() >= 10;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}

public void fillinPartofPath() {
    Point point = new Point();
    point.x = points.get(0).x;
    point.y = points.get(0).y;

    points.add(point);
    invalidate();
}

public void resetView() {
    points.clear();
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

    paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);

    points = new ArrayList<>();
    bfirstpoint = false;

    flgPathDraw = true;
    invalidate();
}

private void showcropdialog() {
    DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = (dialog, which) -> {
        switch (which) {
            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                ((MainActivity) mContext).cropImage();
                break;

            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                    /*// No button clicked

intent = new Intent(mContext, DisplayCropActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("crop", false); mContext.startActivity(intent);
 bfirstpoint = false;*/
                resetView();

                break;
        }
    };

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
    builder.setMessage("Do you Want to save Crop or Non-crop image?")
            .setPositiveButton("Crop", dialogClickListener)
            .setNegativeButton("Non-crop", dialogClickListener).show()
            .setCancelable(false);
}

public List<Point> getPoints() {
    return points;
}
}
```

and this is my MainActivity in which I am adding this cropView to do cropping.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.Region;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.idoideas.stickermaker.R;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Bitmap mBitmap;
private CropView mSomeView;
private Button continueBtn;
private static final int CROPPED_MARGIN = 100;
private Uri uri;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setTitle("Crop Image");

    mBitmap = DataHolder.getInstance().getBitmap();
    mSomeView = new CropView(this, mBitmap);
    continueBtn = findViewById(R.id.continueBtn);

    LinearLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.layout);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp =
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    layout.addView(mSomeView, lp);

    continueBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> withoutCropImage());
}

private void withoutCropImage() {
    Uri uri = getImageUri(mBitmap, Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100);
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("uri", uri.toString());
    setResult(2, intent);
    finish();
}

public void cropImage() {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_picture_preview);
    ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.image);
    Button cancel_action = findViewById(R.id.cancel_action);
    Button save_action = findViewById(R.id.save_action);

    Bitmap fullScreenBitmap =
            Bitmap.createBitmap(mSomeView.getWidth(), mSomeView.getHeight(), mBitmap.getConfig());

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(fullScreenBitmap);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    Path path = new Path();
    List<Point> points = mSomeView.getPoints();
    for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
        path.lineTo(points.get(i).x, points.get(i).y);
    }

    // Cut out the selected portion of the image...
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, paint);

    // Frame the cut out portion...
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(10f);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

    // Create a bitmap with just the cropped area.
    Region region = new Region();
    Region clip = new Region(0, 0, fullScreenBitmap.getWidth(), fullScreenBitmap.getHeight());
    region.setPath(path, clip);
    Rect sourceBounds = region.getBounds();
    Rect destBounds =
            new Rect(CROPPED_MARGIN, CROPPED_MARGIN, sourceBounds.width() + CROPPED_MARGIN,
                    sourceBounds.height() + CROPPED_MARGIN);
    Bitmap croppedBitmap =
            Bitmap.createBitmap(sourceBounds.width() + CROPPED_MARGIN * 2,
                    sourceBounds.height() + CROPPED_MARGIN * 2, mBitmap.getConfig());
    canvas.setBitmap(croppedBitmap);
    canvas.drawBitmap(fullScreenBitmap, sourceBounds, destBounds, null);

    if (croppedBitmap != null) {
        uri = getImageUri(croppedBitmap, Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90);
    }

    imageView.setImageBitmap(croppedBitmap);

    cancel_action.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        DataHolder.getInstance().clearDataHolder();
        finish();
    });

    save_action.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        if (uri != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(uri.toString())) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("uri", uri.toString());
            setResult(2, intent);
            finish();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("uri", "");
            setResult(2, intent);
            finish();
        }

    });
}

public Uri getImageUri(Bitmap src, Bitmap.CompressFormat format, int quality) {
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        src.compress(format, quality, os);
        String dateCreated = SimpleDateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date());

        String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), src, dateCreated, null);
        return Uri.parse(path);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DataHolder.getInstance().clearDataHolder();
    finish();
    super.onBackPressed();
}
}
```

PLease help me, if anyone knows the solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The bitmap is drawn with a natural scale, that's why you only see part of it. Actually your commented parts would rescale it to fit, but you'd need to unscale the resulting points.

Comment: which commented part?